# im trying to install backports in my kali linux but im getting an error while using the code line " make list-defconfigs"

Tags: linux-kernel, kali-linux, error-handling, backports

im trying to install backports in my kali linux but im getting an error while using the code line " make list-defconfigs".screenshot [image: screenshot of terminal] I have done both apt update and upgrade and search everywhere but i cant seem to understand why this is happening. none of the make cammands are working.

Comment: `backports-5.15.8-1` seems like the current version of [Linux kernel drivers backports](https://backports.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page). Using that with Kali would only make sense if you have a very old version of Kali and cannot update it for some reason. So, **please edit your question** to show the outputs of the commands `lsb_release -a` and `uname -a` on your system. Also, there are two modes of using the backports suite: *package release mode* and *kernel integration mode*. Which mode are you trying to use?